Create StructuredQueryDefinition with Marklogic Java API to find all XML files with given element
I’m sorry if there is a trivial answer to this question that I’ve missed, but I’m trying to get a StructuredQueryDefinition object that will search for documents that contain a specific XML element.
The XML search string I might use would be something like this:
<query xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <container-query>
    <element ns="" name="MyTag" />
    <true-query/>
  </container-query>
</query>  

But I’m not sure how I would create a StructuredQueryDefinition using the Java API.  I'm looking for the equivalent of <true-query/> but I'm not seeing one.
StructuredQueryBuilder qb = …
StructuredQueryDefinition  def = qb.containerQuery(qb.element("MyTag"), ?whatGoesHere?);

I did find an ugly hack that allowed me to create my own <true-query/> StructuredQueryDefinition but it is not pretty.  I'm hoping there is a more 'out-of-the-box' way of limiting to XML files that have a given tag, but in the mean time I'll use this class:
package com.marklogic.client.query;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;


/**
 * This is a pretty gritty hack.  I needed to create a StructuredQueryDefinition that
 * would represent the <true-query/> search.  (This was needed to find XML files that
 * contain a given element).  
 * 
 * The StructuredQueryBuilder has a checkQuery method that only allows StructuredQueryDefinition
 * objects that are assignable from the AbstractStructuredQuery class.  Unfortunatly this
 * class is protected so I can't extend it from any class that isn't in the com.marklogic.client.query
 * package.  Additionally the AbstractStructuredQuery default constructor references the builderOptionsURI
 * of its enclosing class StructuredQueryBuilder so I had to first create a class that extended
 * the StructuredQueryBuilder and that class define an inner class that extends the AbstractStructuredQuery
 * class.  
 * 
 * Its not pretty but it does work.  I can create a StructuredQueryDefinition to limit to 
 * document containing a tag using the following
 *   qb.containerQuery(
 *      qb.element(tag), 
 *      new com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilderExt().getTrueQueryDefinition()
 *   );
 */
public class StructuredQueryBuilderExt extends StructuredQueryBuilder {  

    public TrueQueryDefinition getTrueQueryDefinition() {
        return new TrueQueryDefinition();
    }
    
    public class TrueQueryDefinition extends AbstractStructuredQuery {
        
        @Override
        public void innerSerialize(XMLStreamWriter serializer) throws XMLStreamException {
            serializer.writeEmptyElement("true-query");
        }
    }
}


Unfortunately, it appears that true-query and false-query functions have not been implemented and exposed in the StructuredQueryBuilder.
I'll file a bug to get those implemented, but in the meantime you may need to leverage your custom extension, or instead of a true-query use an empty and-query.
StructuredQueryDefinition def = qb.containerQuery(qb.element("MyTag"), qb.and());

